# Fifa 15 Team Management Player Icons

Tags: xbox-one, fifa-15

I really thought the answer to this would be online somewhere!

Does anyone have a key to the symbols in Team Management in FIFA 15? I play on Xbox One.

More specifically, I am intrigued as to what the earth/globe looking symbol is.

Can post a photo if you need it.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the globe icon?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out myself.

The globe icon means that player is on international duties so cannot be picked for the next game.